# Override forwared_port from box in VagrantFile

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

The box I'm using has defined a forwarded port on host:80.
I want to change this setting because 80 is already used on my host.

Setting port forwarding has no effect :

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
```

I tried to override this setting as below but it does not change anything:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
    override.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888, host_ip: "127.0.0.1" 
end
```

How to override parent box settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the forwarding should really work like this:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
```

see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Comment: it's the same with :forwarded_port  and "forwarded_port". And this rule come from the box not from my Vagrantfile